# java loop single node of xml file

Tags: java, xml

I have following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<testsuites xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <testsuite tests="4" failures="3" errors="0" package="HPToolsFileSystemRunner">
 <testcase name="C:\HMS\Functional\Functional_Apply_Leave" report="C:\HMS\Functional\Functional_Apply_Leave\Report" time="138.878906" classname="All-Tests.C:\HMS\Functional" status="fail">
  <failure message="Test failed" />
</testcase>
<testcase name="C:\HMS\Functional\Functional_Overtime_Request" report="C:\HMS\Functional\Functional_Overtime_Request\Report" time="143.9445962" classname="All-Tests.C:\HMS\Functional" status="fail">
  <failure message="Test failed" />
</testcase>
</testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I want to loop in only testcase status using java. if status is passed i want to execute method 1 and if the status is failed i want to execute method 2 using java..................................................................................................................................................................................................following code i have written
it prints all the attribute

```
 private static void loopNode(NodeList nodeList) {

for (int count = 0; count < nodeList.getLength(); count++) {

Node tempNode = nodeList.item(count);

// make sure it's element node.
if (tempNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

    // get node name and value
    System.out.println(tempNode.getNodeName());
    System.out.println(tempNode.getTextContent());

    if (tempNode.hasAttributes()) {

        // get attributes names and values
        NamedNodeMap nodeMap = tempNode.getAttributes();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeMap.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodeMap.item(i);
            System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
            System.out.println(node.getNodeValue());

        }

    }

    if (tempNode.hasChildNodes()) {

        // loop again if has child nodes
    loopNode(tempNode.getChildNodes());

    }

    System.out.println(tempNode.getNodeName());

}

}
```

Comment: So far you only described your requirements. Please add the code you have written so far to solve your problem; and point out where you are stuck. You see, this is not a free "we do your work for you" service where other people, well, do your work. We **help** you solving your problem; we don't solve it for you.

Comment: added my code but it prints all the values

Comment: Sure it does. Because you wrote code that prints all values. Basically you have to use these methods you are currently using do dump values ... to compare those values; and then do different things. Sorry, but this is so basic stuff that I have a heard time thinking how to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at XStream http://x-stream.github.io/
It maps your xml structure to appropriate java objects.

Then you can explicitly extract the 'TestCases-List' of your XML representation object and perform the logic you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done.

Use this for loop to execute methods based on the condition.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeMap.getLength(); i++) {

    if( node.getNodeName().equals( "status" ) ){

        if( node.getNodeValue().equals( "true" ) )
           method1()
         else
           method1()
    }
}
```